# UrlFetchApp.fetch with API

Tags: google-apps-script, zoho

i want to execute one Zoho CRM API and write in my GAS

```
  var result=UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?authtoken=XXXXX&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&xmlData=<Leads><row no="1"><FL val="Company">Your Company</FL><FL val="First Name">Hannah</FL><FL val="Last Name">Smith</FL><FL val="Email">testing@testing.com</FL></row></Leads>');
```

and i have one error

```
Argument non valide : https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords?authtoken=XXXXXX&scope=crmapi&newFormat=1&xmlData=<Leads><row%20no="1"><FL%20val="Company">Your%20Company</FL><FL%20val="First%20Name">Hannah</FL><FL%20val="Last%20Name">Smith</FL><FL%20val="Email">testing@testing.com</FL></row></Leads> (ligne 35, fichier "MySQLtoZohoCRM")
```

but if i paste this URL in my Chrome or FF it's run!!!

[doc API](http://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/insertrecords.htm)

Do you know why i have this error in GAS and not in Chrome ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`:

- [fetch(url)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String%29), and
- [fetch(url,params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch%28String,Object%29)

You are using the first form, but the parameter you provide is failing validation because it is not just a URL. You should be using the second form, with the values you would put after the '?' as options.

Try this:

```
var url = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/insertRecords';
var xmlData = '<Leads><row no="1"><FL val="Company">Your Company</FL><FL val="First Name">Hannah</FL><FL val="Last Name">Smith</FL><FL val="Email">testing@testing.com</FL></row></Leads>';
var options =
  {
     'authtoken' : 'XXXXX',
     'scope' : 'crmapi',
     'newFormat' : '1',
     'xmlData' : encodeURIComponent(xmlData)
  }
var result=UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);

var output = Utilities.jsonParse(result.getContentText());
Logger.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks you for your response, i have try your code but i have already error

<Leads><row no="1"><FL val="Company">Your Company</FL><FL val="First Name">Hannah</FL><FL val="Last Name">Smith</FL><FL val="Email">testing@testing.com</FL></row></Leads>
<response><error><code>4600</code><message>Unable to process your request. Please verify if the name and value is appropriate for the "xmlData" parameter.</message></error></response>

Comment: how can i capture the real value of UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options) ?

Comment: @user2235952 I neglected the need to encode the XML, see updated code. There is no way to see what will be sent to zoho from the GAS server cloud. If you have your own web server, you can change the URL parameter to send the HTTP request there, and then capture the traffic on your server.

Comment: @user2235952 I found [this post](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/apps-script/services/4VqhCfEWWEw) that describes modifying the GAS fetch to masquerade as a browser - it's a few years since that was posted, but might be relevant.